# add pdf and then merge all of them using php is not working

Tags: php

I am reading PDF files from directory on a server and trying to merge them in a single PDF file.

When I am working with one file it works but when I'm trying to read all files:

```
ERROR:Fatal error: Call to a member function addPDF() on a non-object
in C:\wamp\www\PDFMerger\sample.php on line 14
```

```
$log_directory = "samplepdfs/";
global $pdf;
$pdf = new PDFMerger;

//print each file name
foreach(glob($log_directory.'*.pdf') as $pdf) {

$pdf->addPDF('$pdf')
    ->merge('file', 'samplepdfs/TEST3.pdf'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in using same variable name `$pdf`:

```
// here pdf is object of PDFMerger
$pdf = new PDFMerger;

//print each file name
foreach(glob($log_directory.'*.pdf') as $pdf) {
    // Here $pdf is a filename and not a PDFMerger object.
    $pdf
       ->addPDF('$pdf')
       ->merge('file', 'samplepdfs/TEST3.pdf'));
}
```

Using `'` around `$pdf`  will not parse variable inside this string. So, remove single quotes.

Final code can be:

```
$pdf = new PDFMerger;

//print each file name
foreach(glob($log_directory.'*.pdf') as $pdf_file) {
    $pdf->addPDF($pdf_file)
        ->merge('file', 'samplepdfs/TEST3.pdf'));
}
```